# Java generics in C#

Tags: c#, java, generics

Hi I am new to C# generics , what is the right way to rewrite the following code in C# ?

```
public class A <T extends Base>{

    Map<Class<T>,Object> m = newHashMap();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I think I got your intent properly.

```
public class A<T> where T : Base
{
    Dictionary<Type, T> m = new Dictionary<Type, T>();
}
```

No type erasure in C# so you are going to have to change a bit of code.

Comment: should be something like `Dictionary<Type<T>, object> m;`

Comment: I don't think so, in your code if `T` is `string`, you will be able to map `"some text"` to `new object()` which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Cicada you sure about that? In Java Class<T> mean literal/type of class T, not Object of class T

Comment: `Class<String> s = "asdf".getClass();` vs. `String s = "asdf"` - those two are not the same.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but C# has no equivalent to `Class<T>` for the simple reason that there's no type erasure. Closest thing to `Class<T>` is either `T` or `Type` (which is non-generic). It depends what the OP needs. Silly downvotes btw.

Comment: The whole point is that an instance of class X is *not* the same by any stretch of imagination as class X itself. On the other hand `Type<string>` is a pretty good approximation of `Class<String>`.

Comment: @Voo. `Type`. There is no `Type<string>`. As Cicada stated, `Type` is non-generic.

Comment: I think I just psychically understood what OP needs.

Comment: Apparently there is no `Type<string>` in C#, so you need to say `Dictionary<Type, object> m` and the compile-time constraint on what can be stored in `m` as a key is lost. I am open for better solutions.

Comment: @saintali This is *exactly* what I said in a previous comment. Please read carefully.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Right, although I'm not sure why Type couldn't be generic - I don't see any reasons for that limitation.

Comment: @Voo Because C# has no type erasure: it makes no sense to have `Type<T>` since you already have `T`.

Comment: @Cicada and I rescinded my down-vote after you fixed your answer. But note that the loss of compile-time constraints on instances of `Type` has nothing to do with erasure.

Comment: @Voo: It [is not generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) because, as Cicada said, C# has no type erasure. A variable of type `Type<MyClass>` could only ever contain the one instance that describes `MyClass`, i.e. `Type<MyClass> t = typeof(MyClass);` The `Type<T>` object of any subclass (say, `SubClass`) couldn't be assigned to that variable, as `Type<MyClass>` and `Type<SubClass>` aren't assignment-compatible in C#.

Comment: @saintali: `Type` being non-generic in C# has to do with (non-existence of) type erasure. Without type erasure, there is no raw type `Type` for a generic type `Type<T>`, so for any variable of type `Type<T>`, you'd have to specify an actual type argument for `T`. With such an actual type argument - say `MyClass` -, there'd be no possibility to ever assign another value to a `Type<MyClass>` variable than `typeof(MyClass)`, i.e. the one and only `Type<MyClass>` instance that describes class `MyClass`.

Comment: I don't see how .net not having `Type<T>` is related to not using type erasure. I'd say it's more related to C# not having class methods, in particular no virtual constructors or virtual class methods.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper So the real problem is that we can't specify bounded wildcards in C#, not type erasure. I.e. there's no equivalent concept of `Class<? extends String>` (well you can get the same for method parameters)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Java has type erasure and *yet* there is exactly one instance of `Class<String>`, of `Class<Object>`, etc. But *there are* many instances of `Class<? extends Object>` and of `Class<? extends Base>`, and in this case many instances of `Class<T>`, the other instances being for subclasses of `Object`, `Base`, etc.

Comment: @saintali The compile-time constraint is not lost. It just moved from `Class<T>` to `T`.

Comment: You got it wrong, `Map<Class<T>, Object>` should translate to `Dictionary<Type, object>` and the constraint will be lost. If the question said `Map<Class<T>, T>` then you had to translate it as `Map<Type, T>` *and again* the constraint would be lost. Sorry but your answer is again incorrect in its correct form.

Comment: @saintali It might be. As I said, I just guessed OP's intent instead of providing a one-to-one port.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the other posts, the C# equivalent of `class A<T extends Base>` is `class A<T> where T : Base`. But unlike `java.lang.Class`, the C# class `System.Type` is not generic, so there is no equivalent for the concept of `Class<? extends Base>` in C#. Your options are reduced to:

```
public class A<T> where T : Base
{
    Dictionary<Type, object> m = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
}
```

Now you may have:

```
public class Sub1 : Base {}
public class Sub2 : Base {}

....

m.Add(typeof(Sub1), new object());
m.Add(typeof(Sub2), new object());
```

But unfortunately also:

```
m.Add(typeof(string), new object());
```

Your best choice is to make sure that `m` is duly encapsulated so that this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You'd achieve this using constraints, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970

```
public class A<T>
  where T : Base
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using type constraints, like this:

```
public class A<T> where T : Base {

}
```